# Button style in FragmentDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-styles

I've created a simple rating dialog, extending `FragmentDialog`. Below the result:

[image]

But I want obtain a style for the buttons like that one used in the typical dialog used in android

[image]

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: Why aren't you using a regular AlertDialog and set the requested rating layout as its content view? In AlertDialog you can just use the setButton() function, the button will look as in the second image you attached.

Comment: Because, Android documentation encourages the use of FragmentDialog, and Fragment in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/submit_layout"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reload_btn"
            style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and "selectable_item_background.xml":

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Supply STYLE_NO_FRAME to the method setStyle(int, int) of the DialogFragment and use TextViews instead of two buttons in your custom layout should do the trick.